# Fetch specific data from JSON

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.x, url

I already asked that question and read a lot of JSON extraction examples and still I cant handle with that JSON... :( 
 I am trying to get only the 'addr_tag' data without anything else, I can get some other information easily but i dont know the right syntax to get the 'addr_tag'

Thanks!

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen


js1 = urlopen("https://blockchain.info/address/1dice97ECuByXAvqXpaYzSaQuPVvrtmz6?format=json&limit=1").read().decode('utf8')
obj1 = json.loads(js1)

print (obj1['txs']) #I need to know the what to put here instead of 'txs'...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is deeply nested, `txs` is the outer key, the value for `txs` is a list which has a dict with the `inputs` whose values is also a list that contains a dict, inside that dict `prev_out` has a dict as a value that has the `addr_tag`key:

```
print(obj1["txs"][0]["inputs"][0]["prev_out"]["addr_tag"])
```

There are actually 2 `addr_tags` in the json the second is under:

```
print(obj1["txs"][0]["out"][1]["addr_tag"])

Satoshi Dice Change Address
```

If the keys are not always there you can use dict.get:

```
inter = js["txs"][0]
k1 = next((d["prev_out"].get("addr_tag") for d in inter["inputs"] if "prev_out" in d), None)
k2 = next((d.get("addr_tag") for d in inter["out"] if "addr_tag" in d), None)
```

If any key is not in your json, the value will be None so you can just check with an if:

```
 if k1 is not None:
     .......
 if k2 is not None:
      ................
```

Looking at the link the data and format keeps changing from run to run, this function will recursively check all the dicts and pull any `"addr_tag"` values:

```
def rec_get(d, k):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if k in d:
            yield d[k]
        else:
            for v in d.values():
                yield from rec_get(v, k)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from rec_get(v, k)


print(list(rec_get(js, "addr_tag")))
```

using the link json, you get which repeats some keys but you can call `set(..` instead of list:

```
['Satoshi Dice Change Address', 'Satoshi Dice Change Address', 'SatoshiDICE 50%', 'Satoshi Dice Change Address']
```

Comment: Great my friend ! give me your Bitcoin address so i can donate you :)

Comment: Hi,another small question please, lets say i bring some other JSON of an address, like this one :(https://blockchain.info/address/%201PzYwVuTotg15ridCGNnAo8u3dr6bE2Yxy?format=json&limit=1) , how can I "ask" the JSON if '('addr_tag' in (obj4)["txs"][0]["out"][1]' is valid or not? because every JSON came with different format and i need to "ask" him first if he have the 'addr_tag' or not... Thanks...

Comment: So it is only there sometimes?

Comment: yes, sometimes its on (obj1["txs"][0]["out"][0]["addr_tag"]) and sometime its on (obj1["txs"][0]["out"][1]["addr_tag"]). the problem is that when its not in both of them,the code crush because he cant handle with the [1], he just dont recognized him... like in this JSON (https://blockchain.info/address/%201PzYwVuTotg15ridCGNnAo8u3dr6bE2Yxy?format=json&limit=1)

Comment: @Itsko, I added a recursive implementation that will search through all the json, the format seems to be changing all the time so this will at least guarantee you get all the keys regardless